# Spring Data MongoDB Repository - JPA Specifications like

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, dynamicquery, dynamic-queries

Is there something like *JPA Specifications* for Spring Data MongoDB Repositories?

If not, how can I make **dynamic queries** with repositories?

A classic scenario could be a search form with optional fields that the user will fill.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found myself a way.

The trick can be done using **QueryDSL**, in the following way:

First, add the QueryDSL dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl-mongo.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>${querydsl-mongo.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, configure the plugin in order to create Metamodels classes (their names will be the same of the *documents* with the letter *Q* as prefix: eg. `QUser`):

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            ....
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Note the processor class: it's not the QueryDSL default one *com.mysema.query.apt.morphia.MorphiaAnnotationProcessor*, but the Spring Data MongoDB one **`org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor`**:

> Spring Data Mongo provides a custom APT processor to generate the
>   Metamodels instead of the one provided in QueryDSL, it will scan the
>   Spring specific @Document instead of the Morphia specific annotations.

Now we can make our repository interface extending `QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>`:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User>,
        QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QUser> {
}
```

We can now define Predicates when querying the repository:

```
QUser user = QUser.user;            
BooleanExpression predicate = user.name.containsIgnoreCase("John");         
userRepository.findAll(predicate);
```

`QuerydslBinderCustomizer` helps you to define the binding of the Document's properties (see [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe) for further help).

Comment: For an implementation of this and also for the reactive version, there is an example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/mongodb/querydsl

Answer (score 1):

This is update as of:

```
<spring.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
<querydsl.version>4.1.3</querydsl.version>
<spring.data.mongodb.version>1.9.5</spring.data.mongodb.version>
```

use

```
...
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```